# Rails association not loading correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My parent class is sometimes not loading all of its children in an `after_save` callback by the child.

I have two models:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children

  def update_something
    # explained below
  end
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent

  after_save :tell_parent_to_update

  def tell_parent_to_update
    parent.update_something
  end
end
```

I have a test I'm running on it, which just checks 2 things. `parent.children.count` and `parent.children.length`. **Both should be 4.** I realize that count is sometimes different, but (as far as I know) it shouldn't be here.

If I define `update_something` to just iterate over `children`:

```
def update_something
  children.each do |child|
  end
end
```

the test fails--the loop will execute once (and will return the array of a single child--the **first** `child` created).

Otherwise, I can put any code as long as it doesn't mention `children` and it'll work. It is like the call to children is causing the association to load the wrong thing.

**Forcing a reload fixes it:**

```
def update_something
  children(true).each do |child|
  end
end
```

but this is hacky and I would rather fix the root issue if possible.

Is this my bug, or a rails bug (and if so is there something I can do to get around this)?

I doubt it matters but this is a test environment using sqlite3. Though it also will fail in a dev environment if I create and test the records in a single dev console session.

Comment: `children.each do |child|` or `Children.each do |child|`?

Comment: maybe something to do with keywords,  just guessing.

Comment: I thought so at first as well, but in the real code it is very isolated now, and the actual names of the models/methods are extremely domain-specific and unfortunately aren't keywords

Comment: This is test env you say. Does it also fail in dev?

Comment: try reloading object when checking for `parent.children.length` using  this in your tests- `parent.reload.children.length`. That should give you the correct length. I believe that in test environment your parent object is loaded only once and every changes made to its children after loading in parent won't be seen on the parent object unless you reload it

Comment: @Kkulikovskis that should work, but masks the underlying issue too much for my comfort.

Comment: @MilesStanfield I can indeed also get it to fail in a dev console if I create the relevant records in that session. edited problem description to reflect this.

Comment: @matt but why would you worry about reloading objects in tests, when they won't fail in development or production environment. As far as my understanding goes test environment boots up only one instance of the app, while development and production servers create a new instance per request, meaning that there are no frozen instance values possible in a real environment. Please tell me if I'm wrong :)

Comment: I'm guessing this problem occurs when you're adding to the association, right? Have you tried using after_add association callbacks? [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-callbacks)

Answer (score 3):

Stab in the dark, but you may need [`inverse_of`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-inverse-of), which I believe stores the associated objects in the same memory block, as opposed to the different blocks a standard approach would create:

```
#app/models/parent.rb
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, inverse_of: :parent
  ...
end

#app/models/child.rb
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, inverse_of: :children
  ...
end
```

In my own experience, I've found `inverse_of` allows you to call the associative data in the other models. For example, calling `parent.update_something` *without* `inverse_of` would either lead to an error (if `parent` wasn't explicitly defined), or have to build the `parent` object again.

There's a [good write-up here](https://viget.com/extend/exploring-the-inverse-of-option-on-rails-model-associations).

--

I'll delete the answer if it doesn't help.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't seem to fix it. According to the write-up and what I found online, as of rails 4.1 (I'm 4.2) it is handling that automatically. It'd be useful to leave this answer up though, in case it does fix it for someone in the future.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the heads-up. I'll leave it up for posterity!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the children of parent are eager-loaded at some point in your code before tell_parent_to_update is run.

parent.children.count will run a SQL query and return the # of children present in the DB, whereas parent.children.length will return the length of the children array (which is probably already eager-loaded).

I would suggest you manually try to save 1 children object from the rails console and see if the length and count of children in update_something is the same. If it is, your test is probably failing because of some code before it.